# Why bgez and bltz have the same function code in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, machine-code

bgez and bltz have the same function code in MIPS:000001, they are classified from rt filed.However,bgtz and blez have different function code.Why does the designer do that?

Comment: What is the meaning of this question?

Comment: BLTZ:INSTR31..26/INSTR20..16=01/00H  BGEZ:INSTR31..26/INSTR20..16=01/01H    Why bltz and bgez instruction use special encodings?

Answer (score 2):

There are only so many opcodes you can encode with just 6 bits. So in some cases more than one instruction use the same opcode, and additional bits in the instruction word are used to determine the instruction. Or as **MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume I: Introduction to the MIPS32™
Architecture** puts it:

> Opcode values that do not specify an instruction instead specify an instruction class. Instructions within a class are
>   further specified by values in other fields.

They then list those instruction classes and the other relevant fields in the section *A.2 Instruction Bit Encoding Tables*.
So you'll see e.g. that opcode `000001` is the instruction class `REGIMM`, and the instruction within that class is determined by bits 20..16 according to this table (bits 20..19 on the left, bits 18..16 on the top):

```
       000      001     010      011    100   101  110  111
0  00  BLTZ    BGEZ    BLTZL    BGEZL    *     *    *    *
1  01  TGEI    TGEIU   TLTI     TLTIU   TEQI   *   TNEI  *
2  10  BLTZAL  BGEZAL  BLTZALL  BGEZALL  *     *    *    *
3  11    *      *        *        *      *     *    *    *
```

Perhaps it seems arbitrary that `BLTZ` is part of the `REGIMM` group while `BGTZ` isn't. I can't really say *why* that is. In the end that doesn't really matter though. What matters is that there are clear rules for how instructions should be encoded.